# Send mail through localhost

Tags: php, email, localhost

I spend so much time but fail to mail through localhost. I read so much blog and tried as they suggested but I could not heel my issue. So what can i do for sort out this.
I tried also third party like sendmail, phpmailer etc ....
my php.ini file configuration is:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = ******224401@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

any idea will much appreciated...thanx in advance

Comment: Are you connecting to a mail server on your localhost?

Comment: I don't think you can get it to work. Sendmail is out of date. Try using SwiftMailer. http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: @Jack check out this posting on Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page - if it does not work, can you update the question with the php code you are using to send mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to uncomment this line

```
;sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

just remove semicolon

```
sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

and restart your apache